# Linq to Entities and SQL Server 2008 hierarchy id

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, .net-3.5, linq-to-entities

Does Visual Studio 2008 SP1 / .NET 3.5 support Linq to Entities (ADO.NET Entity Data Model / edmx) with SQL Server 2008 R2?  Specifically, the hierarchy id type?  If so, do you have a download link, if not is there a published date when this feature will become available?  I experimented a bit today after installing [GDR R2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=bb3ad767-5f69-4db9-b1c9-8f55759846ed&displaylang=en) to support Sql 2k8 dbproj and the AdventureWorks2008 import failed.

EDIT: thanks devio, I found this by clicking through

> Note: EF 1.0 Compatibility Issues The
>   Entity Framework team would like us to
>   let you know that AdventureWorks2008
>   is a little bit ahead of the curve in
>   terms of the Katmai features it uses.
>   Some datatypes in AdventureWorks2008
>   (such as hierarchyid and geometry) are
>   not supported in the entity framework,
>   and some datatypes like date and time
>   can cause problems. The workaround is
>   to exclude tables like
>   Production.Document from your model if
>   possible since there is currently no
>   support for the hierarchyid datatype
>   in Entity Framework 1.0. Unfortunately
>   the Entity Framework tooling which
>   updates your model from the database
>   will pull in tables like
>   Production.Document even if they were
>   specifically excluded when the model
>   was created, so use of that feature on
>   AdventureWorks2008 is not supported at
>   this time. We look forward to a
>   follow-on release of Entity Framework
>   which has full Katmai type support.

Any word on when the next version of EF is available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, [no, not HIERARCHYID](https://connect.microsoft.com/dataplatform/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=430515).

I don't know if it will be in v4.

Answer (score 1):

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399790.aspx):

> New data types introduced in SQL
>   Server 2008 are not supported
>   explicitly by this version of the
>   Entity Framework. These data types
>   include the following: hierarchyid,
>   geography, and filestream. Because the
>   AdventureWorks 2008 database features
>   these new data types, errors occur
>   when generating a data model that is
>   based on the AdventureWorks 2008
>   database.

(which is kind of funny considering AdventureWorks *does* implement new server features which the development tools do *NOT* support)